# Using Core Data in remote SQL

Tags: objective-c, sql, ios, core-data

I want to use Core Data for managing remote sql server. Is that possible? I checked through the apple documentation and it only shows about SQLite, but on CS193P stanford lectures they say that it is possible to do, but don't say how?

I currently use a bridge with php queries, but that is not OOP way

Thank you.

Comment: When you say remote, do you mean a web service? It is certainly possible, and I recommend using [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) to accomplish it (if you have enough data to warrant it, at least).

Comment: Found something very interesting - AWS(amazon web services), RestKit does not have good customer support, and it hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: RestKit does not have customer support, because it does not have customers. It is an open source project. You're also comparing apples and oranges. AWS will be suitable to use for your backend but it does not solve the problem you are asking, it is just a means to an end.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, the answer is no:

> [How do I use my existing SQLite database with Core Data?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-SW2)
>
> You don’t. Although Core Data supports SQLite as one of its persistent store types, the database format is private. You cannot create a SQLite database using native SQLite API and use it directly with Core Data (nor should you manipulate an existing Core Data SQLite store using native SQLite API). If you have an existing SQLite database, you need to import it into a Core Data store (see “Efficiently Importing Data”).